# How match and mark several keywords in string with php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

This is my current code:

```
# highlight keywords in string
function highlight($string, $keyword) {
    return preg_replace("/".preg_quote($keyword)."/ui", "<span class=\"h\">$0</span>", $string);
}
```

If I execute this code:

```
$string = "The house is very big.";
echo highlight($string, "hous");
```

It will return:

```
The <span class="h">hous</span>e is very big.
```

Now I'm trying to send several keywords to the 2nd parameter of the function as an array, and all those matches should be highlighted. Example:

```
echo highlight($string, array("hous", "big");
```

...should return:

```
The <span class="h">hous</span>e is very <span class="h">big</span>.
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: That will be fun when you call it with `highlight($string, array("house", "pan");`: invalid HTML will come out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `$keywords` contains an array of values rather than being of a `string` type:

```
function highlight($string, $keywords) {
    $keywords  = is_array($keywords)
        ? implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $keywords))
        : preg_quote($keywords);
    return preg_replace("/$keywords/ui", "<span class=\"h\">$0</span>", $string);
}
```

[PHP live demo](https://3v4l.org/1OhEB)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do this:

```
function highlight($string, $keywords) {
    return preg_replace("/".implode('|', $keywords)."/ui", "<span class=\"h\">$0</span>", $string);
}

$string = "The house is very big.";
echo highlight($string, ["hous", "big"]);
```

Note: `implode('|', $keywords)` since the `|` pipe symbol would allow you such flexibility.

For more insight, see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html